# IIS Session Timeout after 1 hour despite server interaction every 30 minutes

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, iis, timeout

We have a ASP.NET web application running on IIS 7.5 or above which times out after exactly one hour. Which is correct in a way that the Application Pool's Idle Time-out value is set to 60 minutes, as is the timeout under system.web/sessionState. But we have an automatic refresh mechanism that loads our website's content every 30 minutes, thus interacting with the server. We would assume this "resets" the timeout, but after one hour the Session closes anyway. Is there another timeout setting we're missing here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Can you examine your web logs to confirm the following statement?

> But we have an automatic refresh mechanism that loads our website's content every 30 minutes, thus interacting with the server.

If the "automatic refresh mechanism" interacts with your web server, then that interaction should be recorded in your web logs. If its not there, then I would suspect that the loading of the website's content is not doing anything that would reset the Application Pool's Idle Time-out timer for your web application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will do that on Friday since I have no access to the server until then. It definitely executes server side code with the automatic refresh. I would assume that resets the app pool's time-out.